# How do i make my button div responsive in every device

Tags: html, css, button

I am working on a simple project. I need some help in making my button responsive in every device. When I see this in iPad, the button moves top in device. I want it in middle of page in every other device.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container ">
   <a href="video.php"
         <button type="button" id="screen" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 25%"> btn-Start ScreenSaver-btn </button>
   </a>    
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on SO: please take some time to review your post before submitting: the CSS code is missing and you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. 
As a side note you have a button inside a link (which is invalid) and the link tag itself is malformed.

Comment: May be this can help you: https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8/

Comment: Start with creating semantic valid HTML. A `<button>` inside a `<a>` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. First of all ... dont use the html button tag inside a-tag. You can display the link itself as a button by only using the bootstrap classes.

example-code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container" style="height:300px;">
   <a href="video.php" class="btn btn-primary" id="screen"> btn-Start ScreenSaver-btn
   </a>
</div>
```

Note that I use height:300px in the div style as an example

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` to your container, Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/8ka034yz/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container ">
   <a href="video.php">
         <button type="button" id="screen" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 25%"> btn-Start ScreenSaver-btn </button>
   </a>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
     html,body{
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container h-100">
    <a href="video.php">
    <button type="button" id="screen" class="btn btn-primary"> btn-Start ScreenSaver-btn </button>
    </a>
</div>
```